# Let $k,n$ be integers with $2\leq k \leq n$, consider set $S = \{1,2,...,n\}$. What is the #of $k$-element subsets $S$ that do not contain $1$ and $2$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> **Question 1:** Let $k,n$ be integers with $2\leq k\leq n$, consider set $S=\{1,2,...,n\}$. What is the number of $k$-element subsets of $S$ that do not contain $1$ **and** do not contain $2$?

A) $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

B) $\binom{n-1}{k}$

C) $\binom{n-2}{k-2}$

**D) $\binom{n-2}{k}$**

**Attempt:** Kind of lost on how to attempt this so I took a shot in the dark.

I took $n=3$, so $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and found all $8$ subsets of $S$. I found that only $2$ subsets have no $1$ and $2$ (empty set and $\{3\}$). So I'm assuming $k=2$ and taking $n=2$ satisfies the option $A$ being $2$? The answer is option $D$ though.

> **Question 2:** Let $k,n$ be integers with $2\leq k \leq n$, consider set $S={1,2,...,n}$. What is the number of $k$-element subsets of $S$ that do not contain $1$ **or** do not contain $2$?

A) $\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

B) $\binom{n-2}{k}$

**C) $\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-2}{k-2}$**

D) $\binom{n}{k}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

**Attempt:** I tried doing the same thing as Q1. I got $4$ subsets that don't have $1$ and $4$ subsets that don't have $2$ using $n=3$. I got $8$ total? But that didn't make any sense.

I'm pretty lost on how to approach these logically. I can't grasp the k-element stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1, the answer should be D.  If you exclude $1$ and $2$ you have $n-2$ elements left of $S$.  You have to select $k$ of them.  There are $n-2 \choose k$ ways to do that.

For 2, the same logic as in 1 says there are ${n-1 \choose k}$ subsets that do not contain $1$ and the same ${n-1 \choose k}$ that do not contain $2$, but we have counted the ones that contain neither twice, so we have to subtract them once and have $2{n-1 \choose k}-{n-2 \choose k}$.  This is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: "we have counted the ones that contain neither twice"

Could you elaborate on that part please?

Comment: Sets that have neither $1$ nor $2$ were counted among the ones that do not have $1$ and counted again among the ones that do not have $2$.  In your example with $n=3$ there are two $1$ subsets that do not contain $1, \{2\}$ and $\{3\}$.  Similarly there are two $1$ subsets that do not contain $2$, but $\{3\}$ is one of them.  There are $3\ 1$ subsets that either do not contain $1$ or do not contain $2$.  The formula above is $2\cdot 2-1=3$